# Using Arrayformulas with Sumifs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs

I'm trying to build an array formula in Google Sheets to calculate the percentage a certain item will appear on a given shelf, based on the weighted odds of all the items on the shelf. E.g., if Shelf A contains items 1, 2, and 3, each with a weight of 10, then the percentage of the shelf occupied by each item would be 10 / sum(10+10+10). There are multiple shelves with multiple items containing different weights on each shelf

[image: https://i.imgur.com/yRIF9cG.png]

I've tried combining a `sum` with a `filter` within the arrayformula to sum up the weights for only the items on the item's particular shelf, but she collective percentages of all of the items on each shelf do not add up to 100

```
={"% of Shelf"; arrayformula(if($B$15:$B="","",$H$15:$H/sum(filter(H:H,A:A=A15))))}
```

Is there another approach I should be taking? I'm not super familiar with array formulas in general, but since the number of rows I'll have will be variable, I'd rather not use a simple `SUMIFS` without the arrayformula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SUMIF with an array of the shelf ID's as its criteria:

```
=ArrayFormula(filter(to_percent(B2:B/sumif(A2:A,A2:A,B2:B)),A2:A<>""))
```

[image]